# Big Theta Proof: May I chose any constant?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

I have the following assignment:

> Prove that $\sum^n_{i=1} i2^i \in \Theta(n2^n)$

My current approach thus far is the following:

Since we need to prove $k_1 \cdot n2^n \le \sum^n_{i=1} i2^i \le k_2 n2^n$ I chose $k_1 = 1$ and $k_2 = 2$. This holds true to my condition. However I'm unsure whether I can just freely decide on using those two.

Therefore my question is:

> Am I allowed to chose any constant factor I want in a $\Theta$ proof (given that the condition holds true)?

Comment: Any **positive** constant ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as long as the constant conforms to the definition of $\Theta$, that is it

- is positive and
- independent of $n$.

This follows directly from the definition of $\Theta$, which requires only the *existence* of *some $c_1, c_2>0$* (in typical formulations).

You may find [our reference questions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/846#846) helpful; in particular, there are more convenient ways to prove such claims besides checking the definition explicitly.